# redirect url using .htaccess [R=301,L]

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, sef

i want to redirect page url using .htaccess [R=301]

original url : http://www.encros.fr/la-boutique-encros/recharge-toner

redirect url : http://www.encros.fr/recharge-toner

anybody can help me ?

Comment: If you are running on Apache, look up mod-rewrite

Comment: yes, i am working on apache, but i don't know how to url redirect usign .htaccess @MarcAudet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^recharge-toner$ /la-boutique-encros/recharge-toner [L]
```

Comment: it is not working, it's gives 404 error. @sumit

Comment: I have updated code now try it

Comment: what is actual use of [R=301] in .htaccess ? @sumit

Comment: if you want to do permanent redirect than you can use `[R=301] ` but here in your case there is no need of it

Comment: but that code does not work.how to solve this problem ?

Comment: because it is already redirected by old rule, show me that rule I can help you better

Answer (score 4):

You need something like this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    ^/la-boutique-encros/recharge-toner$  /recharge-toner  [R=301,L]
```

The `[R=301]` flag sets the return code. The `[L]` flag prevents other rules from being applied to this specific rewrite.

References:
About rewrite: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

About the rewrite flags: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html